# how to open visual studio solution explorer using mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

The solution explorer is not showing, could you please tell how to open it. 
I only know how to open on windows not mac.

```
       I tried the view-> solution explorer but it's not the same on mac
```

Answer (score 14):

Go to `View` -> `Pads` -> `Solution`.

The `Solution Explorer` will appear on the left side.

Comment: In VS 2019, it's now `View` -> `Solution`