# Visual studio solution explorer in the year 2022

Tags: visual-studio-mac

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072735/how-to-open-visual-studio-solution-explorer-using-mac#:~:text=Go%20to%20View%20%2D%3E%20Pads%20%2D,appear%20on%20the%20left%20side.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072735/how-to-open-visual-studio-solution-explorer-using-mac#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20View%20%2D%3E%20Pads%20%2D,appear%20on%20the%20left%20side.)
Is now obsolete.  The comment to the answer is also obsolete.  Where is the solution explorer for version 1.66 for the Mac?

[image: Visual studio 2022]

Also what's the upside to having the interface change so often?  Is the education worth the improvement?

Answers to questions:
I don't know if we're talking about the same thing.
[image: vs for mac]

Maybe I'm not using visual studio, or I"m using a different one.  I don't usually use ides and its called Visual Studio Code, so maybe I'm using something different?  This probably also explains other weird answers I got.

2. The picture above is the drop down when I click view.  So View|Solution isn't an answer for me because after I click view, there is no option for solution.  I've seen this solution elsewhere, which is why I was specific about the year 2022 and 1.66.  Again, not pertinent if I'm talking about Visual Studio Code and not Visual studio, which until now I thought was the same thing.

Comment: Where did you get that "1.66" version number? VS for Mac never has that as release number.

Comment: The screenshot looks like Visual Studio Code. Visual Studio Code is folder based. The nearest thing to a Solution explorer is View - Explorer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972270/cannot-open-solution-file-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

For VS for Mac 2022, its `View | Solution`.

> "Also what's the upside to having the interface change so often? Is the education worth the improvement?"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/mac-roadmap

VS for Mac 2019/2022 are ambitious releases to rebuild the whole UI from scratch using native macOS UI framework (Cocoa) instead of its legacy cross platform approach (xwt from MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio origin).

That's why you see almost everything changes compared to VS for Mac 2017, and also experience frequent changes in VS for Mac 2019.

As one of the themes is "Experience a new look and feel in Visual Studio for Mac that combines the modern macOS UI with the productive experience you’ve come to know and love in Visual Studio", you should expect some degree of similarity to VS for Windows, but significant differences remain because macOS UI does look and feel differently.

Like the product manager wrote,

> We welcome your suggestions! You can log your suggestions in the [Developer Community](https://aka.ms/feedback/suggest?space=41). You can also report bugs with [Report a Problem](https://aka.ms/feedback/report?space=41).

whatever you want you can raise tickets and let them know. Stack Overflow isn't the right place for such questions/complaints.