# Visual Studio sidebar explorer missing

Tags: visual-studio

New to coding and just installed VS on Mac but I seem to be missing the 'sidebar panel' Tried 'View' but there is no option for 'Appearance' Do I have to install a specific extension?

Sorry if this question was asked, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to open visual studio solution explorer using mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072735/how-to-open-visual-studio-solution-explorer-using-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>⌘ + B</kbd>, in windows it's <kbd>ctrl + B</kbd>